# Getting a template element content or text from ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, mobile, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 C# and SQLite application. I'm really new to Windows Phone applications and usually work with PHP and JS.

There is a LongListSelector, which every item is a Button. Each Button should reference to an ID which is binded from a class of SQLite:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsRadios" ItemsSource="{Binding Radios}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>
```

DataTemplate1:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnFoo" Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate1}" Click="btnFoo_Click" />
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True" x:Name="ContextMenu" >
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="btnEditFoo" Header="edit" Click="btnEditFoo_Click"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="btnDeleteFoo" Header="delete" Click="btnDeleteFoo_Click"/>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

ButtonControlTemplate1:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
       <TextBlock x:Name="lblName" Text="Name" />
       <TextBlock x:Name="lblCountry" Text="Country" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I need to, when a user clicks in one of these buttons, on the event Click, get this ID value that represents a row on SQLite to then run a `select * from table where ID = ...`, for example.

In JavaScript, I would add a attribute `data-id` and handle the event like:

```
this.getAttribute('data-id');
// run an AJAX request
```

My first idea was to bind to  `Content` of each button the ID, so I could run on `btnFoo_click`:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
var ID = sender.Content;
// Do SQLite select.
```

But this doesn't seems to be the correct way to do it. Also, further on I have to work with the same concept on ConceptMenus (on hold, two options: Edit and Delete would show. These must do actions to the element which the user was selecting.)

Also I thought that I could access the template of the button and find a hidden element with the same idea of binding a value to its `Text` or `Content` attribute. But I couldn't find a way to select element from a template, kind of like jQuery's find: `$('.parent').find('.element-i-need');`

Sticking with this second idea, how could I search of elements by their names on a `ControlTemplate` of the clicked button/element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, do you know that you can get hold of the model via the `DataContext`?  That's the most direct way to do it in a click handler:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
var viewmodel = btn.DataContext as MyItemModel;
var ID = viewmodel.ID;
// Do SQLite select.
```

---

For the second, you can't access template elements directly from outside the control (there is [`GetTemplateChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.gettemplatechild(v=vs.95).aspx), but that is a protected method).  The rough equivalent to the JQuery "find" would be to trace down the [visual tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild(v=vs.95).aspx), but that's pretty bad form in XAML, and doesn't always work (not everything is in the visual tree, Popups for example).  You could however subclass the `Button` control, and expose a public property that makes use of `GetTemplateChild`.

Ideally though, your model logic shouldn't be interacting with the UI at all.  When possible it is best to use `<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" ... />` where "SomeCommand" is an `ICommand` implementation, rather than `<Button Click="CodeHandler" ... />`.  That can be easier said than done, though, especially in WP Silverlight without the `FindAncestor` binding ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `DataContext` is something that I totally left behind, because it seems to be kind of complicated to understand, but actualy exactly what I need. Since the LongListSelector is binded by `Radio`, its children also has this attribute setted already, right?

For the jQuery's find method, I was expecting that it wouldn't be easy or even possible. I think sticking with DataContext and understanding it, would help me a lot. Thank you!